# Puppet - hiera not assigning parameters to module

Tags: hiera

According to the [Puppet documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html) on hiera, the following example should work, but for some reason it's not passing the parameters to the module.

I have a simple module called `hello`, which takes in parameters with `hello::talk`, and outputs a file at `/home/user/hello.txt`.

Here's the class:

```
class hello {
    // other stuff
}
define hello::talk (
    $say_hello = true,
    $message = '',
    $say_goodbye = false,
) {
    file { '/home/user/hello.txt':
        owner => root, group => root, mode => 0755,
        ensure => file,
        content => template('hello/template.erb')
    }
}
```

If within a node, I use it like so:

```
node foo {
    include hello
    hello::talk {'config':
        say_hello = true,
        message = 'howdy!',
        say_goodbye = false,
    }
}
```

It works as expected (Creating the file etc)

But if I try to do it with hiera, I can only get it to include the class, but not do the `hello::talk` bit.

Here's my common.yaml:

```
classes:
    - hello

hello::talk -
    say_hello = true
    message = "Oh dear ..."
    say_goodbye = false
```

And site.pp:

```
hiera_include('classes')

node foo {

}
```

No file is made :(

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I misunderstood the documentation a little Lol ... And I'm still misunderstanding the difference between `class` and `define` ... But I guess my brain will get to that later

I managed to get it to work by changing `define hello::talk` to `class hello::talk` and the common.yaml file to:

```
classes:
    - hello
    - hello::talk

hello::talk::say_hello = true
hello::talk::message = 'Yay! ... Kinda'
hello::talk::say_goodbye = true
```

This leads me onto a new question ... Is there a way that I can restructure the class, so that, like other modules, I only need to include `hello` and can then set the parameters. Also, it would be nice if I wouldn't have to continually use `hello::talk::` to set the parameters ...

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between classes and defines is that a class can be called only once and defines can be called multiple times if you provide different names.

Regarding your last question.

You will need to move your parameters inside your hello class and call the hello::talk class/define inside this (I will presume that hello::talk is a define here):

```
class hello (
    say_hello   = true,
    message     = 'howdy!',
    say_goodbye = false
) {
    hello::talk {'config':
      say_hello   => $say_hello,
      message     => $message ,
      say_goodbye => $say_goodbye,
    }
}
```

With the above structure you can set in hiera:

```
classes:
    - hello

hello::say_hello: true
hello::message: 'Yay! ... Kinda'
hello::say_goodbye: true
```

Comment: Ah that looks a better structure, I'll give it a go later :D